# How do I correctly use applescript 2.3 script library "use" rather than "tell"

Tags: macos, applescript, language

When I use my library this way applescript will not parse the `display dialog` line, treating `dialog` as an identifier!

Can anyone explain why this is not being understood in the way I want it to be? Many thanks!
** UPDATE ** Both the scripts below will now compile and work properly

```
use myLib : script "IHDatabase" -- the name of the library
-- UPDATE -- See also my answer below 
use scripting additions
-- UPDATE -- without the above statement this script will not compile
set db to IHDatabase of myLib at "~/Desktop/TestDB.db" 
-- IHDatabase handler returns an IHDB script object
tell db
    add_sql("drop table if exists testtable;")
    add_sql("create table testtable (firstname, lastname, country);")
    add_sql("insert into testtable values('Ray', 'Barber', 'USA');")
    add_sql("insert into testtable values('jj', 'Sancho', 'Spain');")
    add_sql("insert into testtable values('Adam', 'Bell', 'Canada');")
    add_sql("insert into testtable values('Bruce', 'Phillips', 'USA');")
    add_sql("insert into testtable values('Kim', 'Hunter', 'USA');")
    add_sql("insert into testtable values('Kevin', 'Bradley', 'USA');")
    add_sql("select * from testtable;") -- columns are separated by pipes ("|") in the result.
    set testtable_result to run_sql()
    log testtable_result & return & return
    set title to "So far, the table contents are: " & return & return
    display dialog title & testtable_result buttons {"Done"} default button 1 with icon 1
end tell
```

But if I write it like this, with an extra level of tell nesting, it works OK:

```
tell script "IHDatabase" -- the name of the library
    set db to IHDatabase at "~/Desktop/TestDB.db" 
    -- IHDatabase handler returns an IHDB script object
    tell db
        add_sql("drop table if exists testtable;")
        add_sql("create table testtable (firstname, lastname, country);")
        add_sql("insert into testtable values('Ray', 'Barber', 'USA');")
        add_sql("insert into testtable values('jj', 'Sancho', 'Spain');")
        add_sql("insert into testtable values('Adam', 'Bell', 'Canada');")
        add_sql("insert into testtable values('Bruce', 'Phillips', 'USA');")
        add_sql("insert into testtable values('Kim', 'Hunter', 'USA');")
        add_sql("insert into testtable values('Kevin', 'Bradley', 'USA');")
        add_sql("select * from testtable;") -- columns are separated by pipes ("|") in the result.
        set testtable_result to run_sql()
        log testtable_result & return & return
        set title to "So far, the table contents are: " & return & return
        display dialog title & testtable_result buttons {"Done"} default button 1 with icon 1
    end tell
end tell
```

FYI the library is:

```
property name : "IHDatabase"
property version : "1.0"

--IHDatabase class
on IHDatabase at dbname
    script IHDB
        property loc : missing value -- tells SQLite where to put our db if it doesn't exist, identifies it if it does.
        property head : missing value -- the opening statement of every future command to our db.
        property tail : missing value --ends every query started with "head".
        property sql_stmt_list : missing value -- we build up a SQL program here

        on init(dbname)
            set loc to space & dbname & space
            set head to "sqlite3" & loc & quote
            set tail to quote
            set sql_stmt_list to {}
            return me
        end init

        on add_sql(stmt)
            set stmt_space to stmt & space
            set sql_stmt_list to sql_stmt_list & stmt_space
        end add_sql

        on run_sql()
            set rows to do shell script head & sql_stmt_list & tail
            set sql_stmt_list to {}
            return rows
        end run_sql

    end script
    return IHDB's init(dbname)
end IHDatabase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered that you need to add explicitly `use scripting additions` to have the `display dialog` command recognised properly.
Once you start using `use` then apparently other libraries, otherwise normally available by default, have to be explicitly included by their own `use` statements.

So add

```
use scripting additions
```

to the client of the library (my first file above) and it will compile and run as intended.

Comment: Thanks to [this MacScripter thread's author](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=168712) for alerting me to this solution